# Sum being zero when calculated using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var num1=document.getElementById("number1");
var num2=document.getElementById("number2");

var k=Number(num1.value);
var l=Number(num2.value);

function add(){
    onCout(k,l,function result(a,b){
                return a+b;
    });
}



function onCout(c,d,callback){
    var result=callback(c,d);
    output.innerHTML=result;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   Num1: <input type="text" id="number1" />
   Num2: <input type="text" id="number2" />
   <div id="output"></div>
   <button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

i want to calculate the sum of two input text field when user clicks the add button.But when I did 
`console.log(k);` I am getting **zero**.I dont know hoe it became zero.I also searched how to take the value from text field and they way to take is using `document.getElementById("id")`.value.I have done the same but my result is not coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value of `k` & `l` inside the add function. That is because before clicking the button those values are empty

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("number2");



function add() {
  var k = Number(num1.value);
  var l = Number(num2.value);
  onCout(k, l, function result(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}



function onCout(c, d, callback) {
  var result = callback(c, d);
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Num1: <input type="text" id="number1" /> Num2: <input type="text" id="number2" />
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

You are getting 0 because initially the fields are empty and `Number('')` will give 0

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("number2");

var k = Number(num1.value);
var l = Number(num2.value);
console.log(num1.value, num2.value) // value is empty string
console.log(k, l); // NUmber('') is 0

function add() {
  onCout(k, l, function result(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}



function onCout(c, d, callback) {
  var result = callback(c, d);
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
Num1: <input type="text" id="number1" /> Num2: <input type="text" id="number2" />
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: but since i have put the value of k and l outside the add() function.it will be recognized as global variable. why is it coming zero? can u please clarify me?

Comment: @Randomguy Without a default value, the initial state of the input field is empty (or zero once casted to number). If you get their value outside (hence before the user input) the `add()` function, you will get an empty (zero) value for both input fields. By getting the values inside the function you will be sure to have the correct values the user entered.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 0 because youre getting the values of k and l on page load and not inside your add function which gets called on button click.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the updated values inside the function instead of getting the initials one on load, this can be done as follows:

```
function add(){
     var k=Number(num1.value);
     var l=Number(num2.value);
     onCout(k,l,function result(a,b){
          return a+b;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var k=Number(num1.value);
var l=Number(num2.value);
```

the value must be fetched inside the function add(), as the values will be dynamic.

In the code shown in question, values are fetched only once which makes them pointing to initial only and not change dynamically with user input

```js
var num1=document.getElementById("number1");
var num2=document.getElementById("number2");


function add(){
    var k=Number(num1.value);
    var l=Number(num2.value);
    onCout(k,l,function result(a,b){
                return a+b;
    });
}



function onCout(c,d,callback){
    var result=callback(c,d);
    output.innerHTML=result;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   Num1: <input type="text" id="number1" />
   Num2: <input type="text" id="number2" />
   <div id="output"></div>
   <button id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```